# How to store folders/files tree

Tags: python

I design a multi-threaded application that will monitor and handle files in selected folders (according to user preference).

What is the best way to store information on the files ?
(e.g. User add xxx directory, I need to go over the directory and add all the files and sub dir to my application)

I was considering my own tree structure or using SQLite.

Thanks

Comment: It depends on your environment, size and type of project, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite is a nice solution, as the database wrapper will handle locking of reads and writes (within the database) for you. You can even use a column as your file's read/write lock.

Comment: I read that there are limitations on using SQLite with multithreading. I sthere another way around?

Comment: @user653952 : Two threads cannot work on the same database record at the same time, however it would be very bad to do this anyway. You'll have to be careful of race conditions and the like, but you'd have to watch out for this anyway - what limitations had you heard of?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your environment, size and type of project, etc.

The EASIEST way is to use the **pickle**.

For example the data is in a tuple in this format:

```
actions=(
    {time=..., user=..., action="adddir", name="new folder"},
    {time=..., user=..., action="accessfile", name="/etc/passwords"}
)

#save the data:
f = open('somefile', 'w');
pickle.dump(actions, f)
f.close()

#laod them:
f = open('somefile', 'r');
actions = pickle.load(f)
f.close()
```

Comment: This will however require for you to handle locking and blocking of the pickle file yourself. It depends on how often you expect multiple processes to want to read/write to/from the same pickled file, and whether you want them to be aware of changes made part way through their read/write loop.